# error TS2722: cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' . . (toolbarClick)='toolbarClick($event)'>

Tags: angular, export-to-excel, syncfusion

```
error TS2722: cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' . . (toolbarClick)='toolbarClick($event)'>

Getting above error while adding excel export feature in Syncfusion Grid.


import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { data } from './datasource';
import { GridComponent, ToolbarItems } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids';
import { ClickEventArgs } from '@syncfusion/ej2-angular-navigations';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
<ejs-grid #grid id='Grid' [dataSource]='data' [toolbar]='toolbarOptions' height='272px'
               [allowExcelExport]='true' (toolbarClick)='toolbarClick($event)'>
                <e-columns>
                    <e-column field='OrderID' headerText='Order ID' textAlign='Right' width=120></e-column>
                    <e-column field='CustomerID' headerText='Customer ID' width=150></e-column>
                    <e-column field='ShipCity' headerText='Ship City' width=150></e-column>
                    <e-column field='ShipName' headerText='Ship Name' width=150></e-column>
                </e-columns>
                </ejs-grid>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    public data: object[];
    public toolbarOptions: ToolbarItems[];
    @ViewChild('grid') public grid: GridComponent;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data = data;
        this.toolbarOptions = ['ExcelExport'];
    }

    toolbarClick(args: ClickEventArgs): void {
        if (args.item.id === 'Grid_excelexport') { // 'Grid_excelexport' -> Grid component id + _ + toolbar item name
            this.grid.excelExport();
        }
    }
}
```

error TS2722: cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' . . (toolbarClick)='toolbarClick($event)'>

```
toolbarClick(args: ClickEventArgs): void {
            if (args.item.id === 'Grid_excelexport') { 
                this.grid.excelExport();
            }
        }
```

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in Angular 12 by setting strictTemplates to false in tsconfig.json.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   ...,
   "strictTemplates": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement we have prepared a sample and in tsconfig.base.json file, we have set strictOutputEventTypes as true and strict as false to prevent the “Cannot invoke an object which is a possibly 'undefined'” issue during compilations.

So we suggest you use the above properties to resolve the issue at your end. For your convenience we have attached the code example so please refer to the code for your reference.

Code example:
tsconfig.base.json

```
"compilerOptions": { 
    "baseUrl": "./", 
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", 
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "strict": false, 
    . . . . . . . . . 
  }, 

  "angularCompilerOptions": { 
    "strictInjectionParameters": true, 
    "strictOutputEventTypes": true, 
    "strictTemplates": true 
  }
```

For more information:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38342

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it by using the ! sign to [assert non-null](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
@ViewChild('grid') public grid!: GridComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

May be `args` or  `args.item` is returning `null`. So to resolve this try this below code

```
toolbarClick(args: ClickEventArgs): void {
        if (args?.item?.id === 'Grid_excelexport') { // 'Grid_excelexport' -> Grid component id + _ + toolbar item name
            *this.grid.excelExport();*
        }
    }
```